# Convert iOS app to Android using Apportable - various reference and definition errors when building

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, apportable

I am trying to convert an iOS app using `Apportable`.

Unfortunately i am facing some errors when building using the command `apportable build`. I have tried to Google and search on StackOverflow for solutions on the problem. Found out that adding "add_params" in the configuration.json could help but that doesn't work and i don't exactly know what to add there.
The build output:

```
Packaging resources.
scons: *** [assets/ResourceRules.plist] Source `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/ResourceRules.plist' not found, needed by target `assets/ResourceRules.plist'.
Build/android-armeabi-debug/Cromian.CHASER/Chaser/libChaser.a(ChooseShoppingLocationViewController.m.o):/Users/Anders/Documents/Xcode/iOS_code/Cromian/Chaser/chaser_app/Chaser/ChooseShoppingLocationViewController.m:function L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_54: error: undefined reference to 'OBJC_CLASS_$_MKPointAnnotation'
Build/android-armeabi-debug/Cromian.CHASER/Chaser/libChaser.a(ChooseShoppingLocationViewController.m.o):/Users/Anders/Documents/Xcode/iOS_code/Cromian/Chaser/chaser_app/Chaser/ChooseShoppingLocationViewController.m:function L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_94: error: undefined reference to 'OBJC_CLASS_$_MKUserLocation'
Build/android-armeabi-debug/Cromian.CHASER/Chaser/libChaser.a(ChooseShoppingLocationViewController.m.o):/Users/Anders/Documents/Xcode/iOS_code/Cromian/Chaser/chaser_app/Chaser/ChooseShoppingLocationViewController.m:function L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_99: error: undefined reference to 'OBJC_CLASS_$_MKPinAnnotationView'
scons: *** [Build/android-armeabi-debug/Chaser/apk/lib/armeabi/libverde.so] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
Anders-Friis-MacBook-Pro:chaser_app Anders$
```

I still have problems with `MKPointAnnotation`, `MKUserLocation` and `MKPinAnnotationView`.
They are used in the following class:

ChooseShoppingLocationViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import "NotificationController.h"

@interface ChooseShoppingLocationViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocation *shoppingLocation;
@end
```

ChooseShoppingLocationViewController.m

```
@interface ChooseShoppingLocationViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) MKPointAnnotation *shoppingLocationAnnotation;
@end

...

- (MKPointAnnotation *)getNewShoppingLocationAnnotation
{
    MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    annotation.title = YOUR_SHOPPING_AREA_TEXT;
    return annotation;
}

...

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    userLocation.title = @"";
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location = [userLocation coordinate];
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location, DISTANCE_SPAN, DISTANCE_SPAN);

    if (self.isFirstUserLocation) {
        dispatch_queue_t animateQueue = dispatch_queue_create("show user location", NULL);
        dispatch_async(animateQueue, ^{
            sleep(1.0);
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
                [self.mapView selectAnnotation:self.shoppingLocationAnnotation animated:YES];
            });
        });
        self.isFirstUserLocation = NO;
    }
}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id < MKAnnotation >)annotation {
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        return nil;
    }

    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"DETAILPIN_ID"];
    [pinView setAnimatesDrop:YES];
    [pinView setCanShowCallout:YES];
    [pinView setSelected:YES];
    return pinView;
}
```

Is it now allowed to use these classes with `Apportable`?

Btw if i try to remove the use of these classes i am still getting the error:

```
scons: *** [assets/ResourceRules.plist] Source `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/ResourceRules.plist' not found, needed by target `assets/ResourceRules.plist'.
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Answer (score 1):

The duplicate symbol errors indicate that StoreViewAnnotation is defined both in StoreViewAnnotation.m and main.m.  Does main.m import StoreViewAnnotation.m instead of StoreViewAnnotation.h?

The ChooseShoppingLocationViewController.m errors look like a missing symbol in the app.

The error about _UIRefreshControl is because UIRefreshControl is not yet implemented in the Apportable platform. For now, you'll need to stub around it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

I fixed the errors with `StoreViewAnnotation` and `UIRefreshControl` thanks to your answer.

But i still have problems with the ChooseShoppingLocationViewController.
I edited the question with code from the `ChooseShoppingLocationViewController`

Comment: You can find the assets the app is trying to include by looking in the file ./{appname}.approj/targets/{appname}/Release.final. Then you can make adjustments with configuration.json. For example, find ResourceRules.plist in Release.final. Then put that text in the remove_params section of configuration. If an alternative needs to be added it goes in the add_params section.

Comment: I solved the error with the `ResourceRules.plist`. It happened because the path was referencing XCode with 'Xcode.app' but i installed Xcode 4.6.3 and therefore renamed Xcode 5 to 'Xcode5.app', so i just changed the reference to 'Xcode5.app' and it worked. 

But i still get errors in my `ChooseShoppingLocationViewController` unless i uncomment the parts with `MKPointAnnotation`, `MKUserLocation` and `MKPinAnnotationView` as described in the edited question. 
Do you know why?